# What is the meaning of 'predicate.arg(1)' and 'predicate.arity' in java

Tags: java, predicate

I have some java code I'm attempting to translate into vb.net.   It uses 'predicates', a feature I did not know existed until now, but which exists in vb.net too.

So I read documentation on it, but none of it explains the java code I have, specifically, if you have a variable 'p' declared as a predicate, what does p.arity do, and what does p.arg(0) and p.arg(1) return?

My general impression was that a predicate takes a set of objects and returns a subset that meets a particular criteria, (for instance, given the set of all basketball players, return only those that are over 6 feet tall).  But the following code doesn't seem to have anything to do with that:

```
    // st is assumed to be a list of ECHO predicates
    //
  private void parseInput(StreamTokenizer st) throws IOException
  {

while (st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
  st.pushBack();
  Predicate p = new Predicate(st);
  parsePredicate(p);
} // while
  }


  // PRE: p is non-null
  // POST: performs the additions to the ECHO graph required by the
  //       ECHO predicate; if p is not a legal ECHO predicate, an 
  //       IOException is thrown
  //
  private void parsePredicate(Predicate p) throws IOException
 {
Assert.notNull(p);
String name = p.name();

if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(explainPred)) {
  parseExplain(p);
} else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(dataPred)) {
  parseData(p);
} else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(contradictPred)) {
  parseContradict(p);
} else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(analogyPred)) {
  parseAnalogy(p);
} else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(propositionPred)) {
  parseProposition(p);
} else {
  throw new IOException("ECHO: "+name+" is not a legal predicate name. "+
                                                "Must be one of "+explainPred+", "+dataPred+", "+
                                                contradictPred+", or "+analogyPred);
} // if
  }

  //
  // PRE: p's name is explainPred
  // POST: adds the given explanation predicate to ECHO, adding all necessary
  //       links; throws an exception if p is not a legal explains predicate
  //
  private void parseExplain(Predicate p) throws IOException
  {
//msg("in parseExplain...");
int arity = p.arity();
float weight;
List propList;
String explainee;

if (arity == 2) {
  //msg("arity == 2");
  propList = (List)p.arg(0);
  explainee = (String)p.arg(1);
  weight = (float)explainWeight(propList.length());
} else if (arity == 3) {
  //msg("arity == 3");
  propList = (List)p.arg(0);
  explainee = (String)p.arg(1);
  float strength = Float.valueOf((String)p.arg(2)).floatValue();
  weight = (float)(strength*explainWeight(propList.length()));
} else {
  throw new IOException("ECHO: an explains predicate must have 2 or 3 "+
                                                "arguments: "+p);
    } // if
```

Comment: You have to figure out what `Predicate` is, as [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) doesn't mention the existence of methods `arity` and `arg`, so it likely isn't part of the standard java codebase.

Comment: The class `Predicate` used here has nothing to do with Java's standard `java.util.function.Predicate`. Is it a Microsoft thing?

Comment: I do notice at the top of the code is the following: import predicate.*;   This does not have a java prefix, so maybe its a custom written java library that unfortunately has the same name as a Java feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I assume the following:

arity is the amount of parameters the function takes. You can see that after checking if arity is equals to 2, it reads two arguments (arg(0) and arg(1)). So arg is just the method to get the parameter/argument at the given index.

Then when arity is 3, you can get three args; 0, 1, 2